# High-voltage resistors versus anti-surge resistors

Tags: resistors, ac, high-voltage, surge-protection, over-voltage-protection

I am making a voltage divider with four 1M 1206 thick-film resistors and a single 2.7k resistor. The input to this voltage divider will be mains line and neutral.

I want to measure the voltage at line with respect to neutral, with the nominal voltage being 240 V +/- 1%.

I also want to protect this circuit against lightning surges. For that purpose, I am using four resistors in series to deal with high voltages, something like this circuit:

[image]

I can't decide which type of resistors I should use. Should it be general-purpose resistors, high-voltage resistors or anti-surge resistors?

I have seen similar units fail in the field due to lighting surges, with the burning of resistors and PCB traces in that section.

- Would adding MOVs at input be useful also?
- Does the PCB layout matter much in this section?
- Any other protection device that I should consider?
- How should I select rating of my high-voltage/anti-surge resistors to protect against lightning?

Comment: _”Would adding MOVs at input be useful also?”_ If you have any source impedance, then yes. _”Also, does the PCB layout matters much in this section?”_ Certainly. You need to provide sufficient creepage and clearance.

Comment: What lightning standard do you need to meet? Mind that HV chip resistors may require potting to achieve their maximum ratings.

Comment: PCB layout always matters, but especially when dealing with high voltage events like lightning strikes.

Comment: I like to add a small R/C filter with 100 ohm and 1nF, X qualified, to eat very short high voltage spikes before they jump right across the resistor chain. This chain also is a capacitive divider with some pF and 100 pF parallel to the 2.7 kohm can suppress the feedthrough.

Comment: @jens Can you elaborate your comment with a schematic?

Comment: This circuit shows my idea: http://i.stack.imgur.com/CtPNL.png